# How to allow HTTPS for Grails 3 application on localhost?

Tags: ssl, grails, https

I'm trying to add Facebook login to my application and for that I have to run on HTTPS. I have followed steps described [here](http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/deployment/2017/06/28/running-grails-with-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate.html) and created my SSL certificate. 
After i run *grails run-app -https* i get this error:

```
ERROR org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler [https-jsse-nio-8443]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of the [ciphers] specified are supported by the SSL engine : [[]]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getEnabled(SSLUtilBase.java:87)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:61)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.<init>(JSSEUtil.java:142)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation.getSSLUtil(JSSEImplementation.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:95)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:980)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:573)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at ikariera3.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at ikariera3.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1000)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of the [ciphers] specified are supported by the SSL engine : [[]]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getEnabled(SSLUtilBase.java:87)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:61)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.<init>(JSSEUtil.java:142)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation.getSSLUtil(JSSEImplementation.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:95)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:85)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:225)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:980)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:573)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at ikariera3.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
```

I have this configuration in my aaplication.yml:

```
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
        keyStore: C:\\my path\\ia.p12
        keyStorePassword: mypassword
```

I have tried using key in PKCS12 format with same results.

These are the commands with input values I used to create my PKCS12 format key.

1. `genrsa -out ca.key 4096`
2. `req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.cry`

   - Country Name: SK
   - State or Province Name: Zilina
   - Locality Name: Zilina
   - Organization Name: IKariera
   - Organizational Unit..:
   - Common Name: exampleName
   - Email Address: my.example@gmail.com
3. `req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.cry`
4. `req -new -key ia.key -out ia.csr`

   - Country Name: SK
   - State or Province Name: Zilina
   - Locality Name: Zilina
   - Organization Name: IKariera
   - Organizational Unit..: Code Signing
   - Common Name: codesigning
   - Email Address: my.example@gmail.com
   - Challenge password: mypassword
5. `x509 -req -days 365 -in ia.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey -set_serial 01 -out ia.crt`
6. `pkcs12 -export -out ia.p12 -inkey ia.key -in ia.crt -chain -CAfile ca.crt`

   - Export password: mypassword

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this error? I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check is your self-signed certificate correctly created.

I have created self-signed certificate using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwnEmLx2LRs) and [this](http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/deployment/2017/06/28/running-grails-with-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate.html) this reference. and created and using it successfully.

Please check all steps and check and validate `.p12` file

My `application.yml` file

```
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
      keyStore: YOUR_PATH/ia.p12
      keyStorePassword: YOUR_PASS
```

If you running it on Linux based os then `keyStore` path will be like `/usr/../your-p12-File`and on windows you can use `D:\\ia.p12`

`keyStorePassword` : type same password which you have given in the step of creating certificate.

Your can use any port number and please **remove `enabled: true` and `keyAlias: tomcat` field.** it doesn't required(in my case)

Above steps are tested with grails 3.x

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! But I still got the same error.

Comment: I've added to my question stepps I took in order to create my certificate. Maybe there is some difference compared to your creating?

Comment: I don't know, how you are creating certificate. But I followed YouTube tutorial and done with it. I also got many errors while creating certification. And followed many tutorials but this tutorial finally helps me to create ssl certificate. Please try with it or I'll update all the steps in my answer

Comment: I tried steps from YouTube tutorial. I've posted those to my original question also with used values. Please check it if there is something wrong. But I think this is propably related to some configuration somewhere.

Comment: can you please try `port: 8090` with this? It seems one exception is like `"Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed`

Comment: are you using external tomcat for running ?

Comment: I've tried several ports, but sadly none works :( I'm not using external tomcat. I've also tried to run [github.com/grails-samples/grails-ssl](http://github.com/grails-samples/grails-ssl), but got this error `Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]` and at the end in description `The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.` So it's probably related to some configuration. I've done some research, but I'm still clueless.

Answer (score 0):

please consider this
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

`openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")`